# How to use CKEditor inside .map or .forEach in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I tried almost everything and nothing works.
I have a component "Option" that I use inside a .map in another component "Question". I have a CKEditor in the  component, which works just fine.
But when I try to call "replace('option-' + index) to replace the CKEditor inside of each  component, it does not work.

This is my textarea inside :

```
<textarea name={"option-"+index}></textarea>
```

Then I just call the replace method in `componentDidMount` of my `<Question>` component

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
```

If I try tu use `CKEDITOR.replace('"option-"+index')` inside my `<Option>` component I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle about this problem?

Comment: @LalliNuorteva it's just a textarea inside a loop, and in componentDidMount I'm calling CKEditor.replace('option-'+index);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<textarea ref={"option-"+index}></textarea>

(...)

CKEDITOR.replace(this.refs["option-"+index]);
```

Comment: I tried to use CKEDITOR.replace inside my Option component but I'm getting an error. So I tried to do a CKEDITOR.replaceAll() in my Question component, but it does not work too.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `index` by its `refs`? It looks like you're not really accessing the DOM element.